# Going from Nice airport (Nice St Augustin) to Cannes when arriving late (~9pm)?

Tags: trains, france, transportation, late-arrival

I am considering taking a 3 day stop in Cannes, but the plane I intend to take lands thursday night at 8:40pm in Nice airport.

I have been taking the train from Nice St Augustin to Cannes before, and I remember it is a fair assumption I will be at the train station at 940-10pm the earliest. However, I also remember something about the trains not running that late!

If I land at this time, is it possible to get to Cannes center with train? And if not, what then? Also, I guess a taxi costs my left arm?

Comment: Honestly you are pessimistic. If you arrive at terminal 1 and have to pick up luggage, count half an hour after landing time to be at the station. From terminal 2 add 15 mins. I think you might need to run a little but you will be able to catch the train.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the week, the last train from Nice-St-Augustin to Cannes leaves at 21:45. Given it's a little fiddly to walk to, that probably means if you're not out of the airport by 21:30 consider you've missed it (unless you're confident about the way + running + buying tickets etc)

The other main option is the 200 or 210 bus, run by [Lignes D'Azur](http://www.lignesdazur.com/). You can find the times for that on the [Alpes-Maritimes website](http://www.cg06.fr/fr/servir-les-habitants/deplacements/transport-collectifs/lignes-et-horaires/lignes-et-horaires/). The last 210 express bus leaves the airport at 20:00 so you've missed that. However, the 200 has 20:45 and 21:55 departures from the airport (Terminal 1 only though) which should see you there if you just miss the last train.

Comment: If arriving at terminal 2, taking the T1-T2 shuttle until the stop after terminal 1 saves some time. From T1 it is faster to go straight.

Comment: Also if buying a ticket at the machine would make you miss the train, get on it, it is possible to buy a ticket on board (it will cost 4 more euros, but it is cheaper than a cab ride)